# Moto Voice implementation without root?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g, motorola-droid, driving-mode

The new Moto G4 and Moto G4 plus made by Lenovo,  unlike the other Android Motorola phones, is incapable of texting for you and answering your calls while driving, unlike the predecessors Motorola Turbo 2,  Motorola X pure,  Moto X etc etc. I've tried finding apks online that will install a different version of the app as what can be found in the Turbo 2 but they never installed successfully. Does anybody have any insight as to how I can get the full features out of the Moto apps that are not found in the G4 but are found in most other iterations of the Motorola phones? These features are why I wanted to get another Motorola phone and I was disappointed to find that this is the only one that does not support it.